# Laravel logs wont create file on storage path

Tags: php, laravel, cron

I tried to run my cronjob via `php artisan cronjob:call` on my local machine and I want to append or create a log file in the storage path. But after the cron is finished. There is no file created in the folder. I already `php artisan storage:link` but still not working. Did i miss something?

My command in `kernel.php`

```
$schedule->command('amazon:getTransportContent')->weekly()->appendOutputTo(storage_path('logs/getTransportContent.log'));
```

My cronjob output in cmd, I used `print` statement in printing.

```
D:\admin>php artisan amazon:getTransportContent
Running Cron for getTransportContentWed, Mar 3, 2021 4:50 AM
Cron finished Wed, Mar 3, 2021 4:50 AM
```

But there isnt no file.
[image]

Edit: tried using `mkdir` but still not working

```
$schedule->command('amazon:getTransportContent')->weekly()->appendOutputTo(mkdir(storage_path('logs/getTransportContent.log')))
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this:

```
$schedule->command('amazon:getTransportContent')->weekly()
         ->appendOutputTo('storage/logs/getTransportContent.log'));
```

Comment: how about this 
``` $schedule->command('amazon:getTransportContent')->weekly()
         ->appendOutputTo('/storage/logs/getTransportContent.log'));``` I added "/" before the storage.